# php : replicate the excel price() function in php

Tags: php, excel, excel-formula, phpexcel

I have really been struggling replicating the excel price() function in php.

Has anyone had any experience doing this before? or is it available in phpexcel?

Comment: This question lacks any code to show us that you've made any attempt to solve this yourself. If you've tried something, show us what you've tried, example of the expected output and what you're actually getting. If you _haven't_ tried anything, you need to do that before posting. We can help you with your _existing_ code, but we won't write it for you. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [PRICE() is implemented in PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Calculation/Financial.php#L1649), as shown in the [PHPExcel Documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Documentation/FunctionListByCategory.txt#L125)